# bootstrap slider with lazy load angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i want to add to bootstrap CAROUSEL lazy load like the following example :

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/51muqdLf/5/)

```
 <img data-lazy-load-src=
```

but i get the imgs in the slider using ng-src (angularjs)

how i can handle this example to work with angular bootstrap slider with lazy load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After trying i made this logic**

Html

```
<div ng-app='App'  ng-controller='test' ng-init='imgSliderIndex =0'>
    <button id='more' ng-click="imgSliderIndex = check(imgSliderIndex + 1 );"> more</button>
    <img ng-src='{{imges[imgSliderIndex].path}}'>   
</div>
```

Angularjs:

```
var app = angular.module('App',[]);

app.controller('test', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.imges = [
    {
        name: "Image 1",
        path: "http://demo.averta.net/themes/lotus/agency/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/slider8.jpg"
    },
    {
        name: "Image 2",
        path: "http://demo.smartaddons.com/extensions/joomla17/cache/mod_sj_content_slider/cc021ca251f443c4a934cba184872eff.jpeg"
    },
    {
        name: "Image 3",
        path: "http://demo.averta.net/themes/lotus/agency/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/slider10.jpg"
    }
];

$scope.check = function(value) {
    if ( $scope.imges.length > value) {
       return value;
    }else{
        return 0 ;
    }
}
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an img with ng-src that shows the url only when that slide is reached, like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{$index == carouselActive && 'http://www.google.com/image.jpg' || ''}}"/>
```

Where $index is the current slide and carouselActive is the slide being shown.